How to suppress voltage sags in an AC circuit
I'm working on a 24VAC circuit where I'm encountering brief voltage sags (about 4VAC for 0.018 seconds) that are causing a relay to open and power off a larger machince. What components or devices can I install to filter the power?
Key Requirements:

It needs to stabilize the voltage during these brief sags, but not delay too long since this is a safety circuit.
The EMO circuit works by keeping a relay open, so the load is continuous and steady.
Space is limited, so any solutions needs to be compact

I have done the basic troubleshooting of checking connections and looking for loose wires but I did not find any, so I assume the noise is EMI.

Sounds more like a massive overload for one full mains period, Do you see this sag only on the 24 VAC supply or on the mains as well?

Circuit diagram?  What is happening when sag occurs?  Wire length and diameter.  I'm with Jens on this.  Thin wire and change in load will cause more voltage to be lost to feeder, but we need more info before an answer can be given.

There are ways to delay an AC relay's dropout, such as adding a resonant capacitor, and an alternative would be to add a diode, resistor and capacitor, energizing the AC relay with DC, at lower voltage.
*However, this would be a safety hazard! You state, "It needs to stabilize the voltage during these brief sags, but not delay too long since this is a safety circuit." If this relay stayed energized too long, might that result in loss of life or limb, or destruction of property? You would be responsible for any issue caused by modifying the circuit.
Instead, the control circuit could be powered from a continuous online double-conversion uninterruptible power supply. Even if the line sags for seconds or minutes, it would still power the safety device. However, check that the safety circuit still operates correctly with the UPS -- is it intended to shut down in the event of power failure??
